# Named pipes - Problem with write() and read()

Tags: c++, ipc, process, named-pipes

I am doing programming in C++, under LINUX.
I have two independent processes. I should provide communication using named pipe.

Reader:
-creates FIFO using mkfifo - status = mkfifo(myFIFO, 0666) 
-opens the pipe using open - fifo = open (myFIFO,O_RDONLY)
-reads from the pipe - num = read(fifo, temp, sizeof(temp))

Writer:
-opens pipe - fifo = open(myFIFO, O_WRONLY);
-writes to the pipe - num = write(fifo, string, strlen(string));

I have noticed that the file descriptor returned for read process 
and write process are 0. Also, after command write, I can see on my terminal, the string which should be written to the pipe. I don't know why it is shown on terminal... Also, the number of bytes that are written is 0...

Would you please help me?
Thank you!!!

```
// read.cpp:

#define myFIFO "/temp/FIFO"

int main(){
    int num, fifo, status;
    char temp[32];

    if (status = mkfifo(myFIFO, 0666) < 0) { 
     printf("\n %s \n", strerror(errno));
     return 0;
     }

     if (fifo = open(myFIFO, O_RDONLY) < 0) { 
     printf("\n %s \n", strerror(errno));
     return 0;
     }

     if (num= read(fifo, temp, sizeof(temp)) < 0) { 
     printf("\n %s \n", strerror(errno));
     return 0;
     }

    printf("In FIFO is %s \n", temp);
}
```

And in another file:

```
// write.cpp:

#define myFIFO "/temp/FIFO"

int main() {
    int status, num, fifo;
    char string[]="Testing...";

     if (fifo = open(myFIFO, O_WRONLY) < 0) { 
     printf("\n %s \n", strerror(errno));
     return 0;
     }

     if (num= write(fifo, string, strlen(string)) < 0) { 
     printf("\n %s \n", strerror(errno));
     return 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you run it under strace and post the logs?

Comment: Please post the code where the pipe is named and opened, and where you read/write to it.

Comment: Post your code, it will be easier to help you when we can see your problem.

Comment: I am new on linux, I have tried with strace, but it didn´t work. I tried with strace read.cpp... I must google about strace more...

Comment: you should do `strace your_binary`

Comment: I didn´t know about strace, but I see it can be very useful...
Still, when I try, I get - command not found...

Answer (score 9):

You basically have at least four errors in your code. When you create a FIFO, you have to use a file descriptor returned by "open" call. However, you are comparing it with 0 and assigning a result of a comparison to a variable that was meant to hold a file descriptor:

```
if (fifo = open(myFIFO, O_RDONLY) < 0) { 
    printf("\n %s \n", strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

The correct code should look like this:

```
fifo = open(myFIFO, O_RDONLY);
if (fifo < 0) { 
    printf("\n %s \n", strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

Or like this, if you insist of saving one line of code:

```
if ((fifo = open(myFIFO, O_RDONLY)) < 0) { 
    printf("\n %s \n", strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

And exactly the same story with reading:

```
if (num= read(fifo, temp, sizeof(temp)) < 0) { 
    printf("\n %s \n", strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

Correct code:

```
num = read(fifo, temp, sizeof(temp));
if (num < 0) { 
    printf("\n %s \n", strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

In your code that writes to FIFO there exactly the same two errors.

Comment: You are absolutely right! 
I was looking for a mistake, but I didn´t see this thing...
Clearly, I must practice more and more... 
Thank you!!!

Comment: @MarijaS You are welcome. This is all about order of evaluation. This will come naturally with experience. I'd recommend you not to try to save a line of code while you are learning :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your code: `fifo = open(myFIFO, O_WRONLY) < 0` evaluates as `fifo = (open(myFIFO, O_WRONLY) < 0)`. You get zero because the value `open()` returns is `>= 0`.